# What should I do after if I forgot to report a misdemeanor for a background check?

Tags: background-check

After I graduated from college (about 2 years ago), I was out with friends and we got a disorderly conduct misdemeanor. It was a VERY minor crime. There is nothing else on my record. I think I should have listed it because it also asked to list misdemeanors. I forgot at the moment since I was never asked before and it never came up in my previous jobs.

I had already submitted the form that didn't self disclose any past convictions. The background check is still pending. Do I need to contact my recruiter? I can still disclose supporting documents to HireRight so I can still make sure I listed the misdemeanor even though it wasn't in the official document.

Comment: *I was out with friends and we got a disorderly conduct misdemeanor. It was a VERY minor crime* Note that the vast majority of people never get even this kind of record, so many people will *not* consider it minor.  It certainly would look far worse to seen to hide it, intentionally or not, even to people who regarded the original offense as minor.

Answer (score 3):

Should you get the job if it is based on some form of a lie?

**I would advise to tell the truth and own it - you get to be the one painting the right picture.**

If they find out - you will be perceived as someone who tried to deceive them, and if they won't find out - you will be in fear that this will be discovered eventually (what then?).

On the other hand - if you get declined, I wouldn't think that was because you revealed some facts too late, but because of the facts themselves.